# Windows Explorer integrated media file information

Tags: windows-7

I'm looking for a Windows Explorer extension dll that would add such media information columns as sound track bit depth, total bitrate, discretization rate, total duration for at least `flac` and `mkv` file formats.

For example, `flac` and `mkv` file formats are not supported by Windows 7, so the media columns show nothing, and that's why I'm asking for this.

Comment: Two thoughts:
- Change the "folder customization" to "optimize for music"
- Change the association of flac to a program that can open it.

Unfortunately, you can't seem to add metadata to certain file types. I have tested this on my machine with a FLAC file, but it seems while windows displays the columns, they're empty - and they're empty, because if you inspect the file in the "properties" they're empty. It seems the "root cause" of this isn't that windows doesn't support it, but the tags are empty.

I'm experimenting with editing the tags, and get back to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research and frustration with editing untagged media marked as readonly, it seems it's possible to enable Windows Explorer to read FLAC information. The program is called Windows 7 FLAC Property Handler. There's an [article about it](http://blog.dabasinskas.net/enable-flac-support-on-windows-8/). Use this if you JUST want FLAC support.

This assumes your FLAC files are tagged properly, if they aren't you'll have to tag them with something like EasyTag.

There is a solution for both FLAC and MKV called [Icaros](http://shark007.net/tools.html). I downloaded it and I can see some metadata about MKV files in Windows File Explorer now, too.

Comment: I use MPC and Icaros that came with it, they do show more info about MKV files, but not for FLAC. How exactly do I enable display of info for FLAC?

Comment: Have you tried Windows 7 FLAC Property Handler? Maybe Icaros does not support FLAC or you need to update.

Comment: Windows 7 FLAC Property Handler helps to make Windows Explorer to show media attributes for FLAC, and after reinstalling Icaros, attributes for MKV also appeared.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old post, but for those that may stumble upon this in the future, here it goes in case it helps:

I use [dbPowerAmp](https://www.dbpoweramp.com/) and in addition to running standalone, it has the option to integrate into Windows file explorer. This allows metadata to be seen directly from Windows and edited on the fly. dbPowerAmp can also be expanded with codecs for many media formats.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, see: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/can-i-find-the-total-play-duration-of-all-music/b34a810b-2c77-4491-a912-2a01cb4f3c27?auth=1

You can select the audio files in a folder, then

1 look in the Details pane at the bottom of your Windows explorer window [switch this on in Organise, Layout, Details pane]

2 right-click, Properties, Details tab.

Both ways will show you the total length of the selected files.

If you want to include subfolders then you'll need to do a search on the top level folder of interest - search on type: mp3 or wma or whatever format you use and it will return all the corresponding files within that folder tree. Select them all in the search results window and then as I've written above.

If you have used a mixture of audio formats, you'll have to repeat the procedure for each type.